# the garbage collection with html5

Tags: html, garbage-collection, local-storage

i had known that html5 added a character that we have local storage at least 5MB to use ; but i can't find how to do garbage-collection for Local Storage ?  the browser will do it for client?

Comment: Garbage collection usually means freeing up space from the memory from unused variables and objects. Do you mean how long stuff put in local storage will be stored there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From:  [Web Storage Editors draft](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#disk-space)

User agents may prompt the user when quotas are reached, allowing the user to grant a site more space. This enables sites to store many user-created documents on the user's computer, for instance.

Test to see if limit is breached:

```
function test(value, name) {
  try {
    localStorage.name = value;
    return true;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Clear local storage:

```
localStorage.clear();
```

It doesn't look like there's any garbage collection:

[Local Storage Quota test](http://arty.name/localstorage.html)

Answer (score 0):

yes browser itself do this(garbage collection), if you turn on your browser's debugger window( pressing f12 ) and start timeline you can see gc event firing automatically,

Comment: I *think* the question is about local-storage quotas, rather than JS garbage collection?

Comment: **but i can't find how to do garbage-collection ? the browser will do it for client?** i think this question is about garbage collection , not about global storage quotas..

Comment: You can clear the local storage as shown in my answer.  But the browser doesn't do any "Garbage Collection" for local storage.  The user can remove any "stored items".